# QLayout setGeometry (in PyQt 5.14) now ignores negative values. Is there a workaround?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

We have an application which contains a custom-made QLayout. The idea with the layout is that we want to place children of the layout partially outside the layout's frame, thereby clipping the rendering of the child.

In PyQt 5.10 this worked perfectly fine. For example we could:

```
child.setGeometry(-100, 0, 200, 200)
```

.. which would place the child 100px outside the left border of the layout, thereby hiding the left-most half of the child.

In PyQt 5.14, this no longer works. With the same code, ie

```
child.setGeometry(-100, 0, 200, 200)
```

the child is now placed exactly at the left border rather than 100px outside it. No error or exception is raised, it just silently interprets negative values as 0.

Using positive values for the positioning still works, so that

```
child.setGeometry(100, 0, 200, 200)
```

... indeed puts the child at 100px right of the left border.

So question: Is there a way we can get the same behavior as before in PyQt 5.14, so that we can clip children of a layout by placing them outside the boundary of the layout?

Comment: I don't see that effect on my system (I'm using version 5.14.1 on Windows). Could you post a example that fails for you?